# How to insert custom icon on the toolbar using TKINTER in PYTHON specifically in LINUX?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to do the same using the following code:

```
# A Python program to create root window with some options
from tkinter import *

# create top level window
root = Tk()

# set window title
root.title('Tkinter Demo')

# set window size
root.geometry('500x500')

# set window icon
root.wm_iconbitmap('PYTHON\Graphical User Interface[GUI]\pythonlogo.ico') # this line won't work for linux

# display window and wait for any events
root.mainloop()
```

and i also tried:

```
# A Python program to create root window with some options
from tkinter import *

# create top level window
root = Tk()

# set window title
root.title('Tkinter Demo')

# set window size
root.geometry('500x500')

# set window icon
img = PhotoImage(file='PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/pythonlogo.xbm')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, img)

# display window and wait for any events
root.mainloop()
```

The above code worked totally fine in Windows, but for linux i used the image file formats: .png,.jpeg,.gif,.ico,.xbm,.xpm but none of them worked.

I know the .png,.jpeg cannot be used. And, .gif,.ico formats only work on windows. I found from several forums that .xpm or .xbm formats worked fine. But, that was not true in my case.

I got the following error with .xpm as well as .xpm formats:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/pythonlogo.xbm"
```

I've been struggling with this since quite a while.
Any pointers or help towards the topic is well appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `root.wm_iconphoto(True, img)`, where `img` is a `PhotoImage` created from a .png or .gif image file.

Here is the docstring of the method:

> `wm_iconphoto(default=False, *args)` method of tkinter.Tk instance
> Sets the titlebar icon for this window based on the named photo images
> passed through args. If default is True, this is applied to all future
> created toplevels as well.
>
> The data in the images is taken as a snapshot at the time of
> invocation. If the images are later changed, this is not reflected to
> the titlebar icons. Multiple images are accepted to allow different
> images sizes to be provided. The window manager may scale provided
> icons to an appropriate size.
>
> On Windows, the images are packed into a Windows icon structure. This
> will override an icon specified to wm_iconbitmap, and vice versa.
>
> On X, the images are arranged into the _NET_WM_ICON X property, which
> most modern window managers support. An icon specified by
> wm_iconbitmap may exist simultaneously.
>
> On Macintosh, this currently does nothing.

In your code:

```
from tkinter import *

# create top level window
root = Tk()

# set window title
root.title('Tkinter Demo')

# set window size
root.geometry('500x500')

# set window icon
img = PhotoImage(file='PYTHON/Graphical User Interface[GUI]/pythonlogo.png')
root.wm_iconphoto(True, img)

# display window and wait for any events
root.mainloop()
```

I use this in Linux and it works.